# Terraform: put variables in tfvar file not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I defined a variable map my_role in terraform and set its value in abc.tfvar file as follows. if I assign account id as actual value, it works, if I set account id as a variable, it does not work. Does it mean tfvar file only allow actual value, not variable? By the way, I use terraform workspace. Therefore my_role is different based on workspace I select.

The following works:

```
my_role = {
   dev = "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/myRole"
   test = ...
   prod = ...
}
```

The following does not work:

```
my_role = {
   dev = "arn:aws:iam::${lookup(var.aws_account_id, terraform.workspace)}:role/myRole"
   test = ...
   prod = ...
}
```

The following does not work either:

```
lambdarole = {
   dev = "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:role/myRole"
   test = ...
   prod = ...
}
```

does

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following the example on [Input Variables](https://www.terraform.io/intro/getting-started/variables.html#maps)?

You can define your `abc.tfvars` file with:

```
variable "my_role" {
    type = "map"
    default = {
        "dev" = "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/myRole"
        "test" = "..."
        "prod" = "..."
    }
}
```

And access it with `"${lookup(var.my_role, terraform.workspace)}"`.

Also, according to the [from a file](https://www.terraform.io/intro/getting-started/variables.html#from-a-file), the variables defined in `.tfvars` files are automatically loaded if you name the file `terraform.tfvars`, if not, you have to pass as an argument with `-var-file=...`

Cannot test it right now, but probably is something in this way.

Comment: aderubaru: Thanks, variable my_role is defined at variable.tf files. Like I said, in tfvar file. I can assign my_role with "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/myRole" but cannot assign "arn:aws:iam::${lookup(var.aws_account_id, terraform.workspace)}:role/myRole" or "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:role/myRole". I can only assign the later two in tf file, not tfvar file,

Comment: aderubaru: your solution is what I do currently. but I am asking whether I have a way not to even mention 123456789012 at all, just get account using ${lookup(var.aws_account_id, terraform.workspace)} or ${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}. My conclusion is I cannot do it in *.tfvar

Answer (score 0):

I am replying when terraform 0.12 version is latest one.  Solution is simple, you can create one file say vars.tf and declare variables in it.

Example - `variable "xyz" {}`

Now create terraform.tfvars and initialize it.

Example - `xyz="abcd"`

No need to pass any runtime args, it will be picked directly.

Answer (score 0):

Terraform has aws_caller_identity data source. You do not need to mention or hand code account id anywhere. It can be fetched using this source.

In any of your .tf file, just include this source and then you can fetch relevant argument value.

This is how you can do it. Define this in any *.tf file

```
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}
```

Now where ever you want the value of arn or account id, it can be fetched using :

For account id(For terraform0.12):

```
data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id
```

In your case, it would be like this :

```
dev = "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:role/myRole"
```

But in order to this work, you need to define data source like shown above in any *.tf file.

For more help, refer following:

URL : https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/caller_identity.html